# What is the use case that multiple Exception Logger are possible to setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

With `ASP.NET Web API 2.2`

- you can do global exception handling with `ExceptionHandler` class.
- you can do global logging handling with `LoggingHandler` class.

The latter allows multiple setup, but why?

What is the use case that I could need that feature?

From the `ASP.NET` source code

```
public DefaultServices(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
  //... removed for clarity

  this.SetSingle<IExceptionHandler>((IExceptionHandler) new DefaultExceptionHandler());

  this.SetMultiple<IExceptionLogger>();
  this._serviceTypesSingle = new HashSet<Type>((IEnumerable<Type>) this._defaultServicesSingle.Keys);
  this._serviceTypesMulti = new HashSet<Type>((IEnumerable<Type>) this._defaultServicesMulti.Keys);
  this.ResetCache();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging to multiple sources.

I needed to display log messages in real time on dashboard, but we also wanted to persists the logging to storage. Although this could be done with a single logger do both, but we preferred to use multiple loggers, which imho is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: logging to a dashboard. How did you get the logging data from the ExceptionLogger class to the client on the dashboard?

Comment: We did not return any response, we simply logged it. We did pass the messages with SignalR to our dashboard (which was a separate system)

Comment: multiple sources... that I did not think of that... easy 50 points ;-)